# Find files without a number

Tags: find, filenames, wildcards

I am trying to write a simple script that will iterate through all drives except sda. Right now I have this

```
for i in $(find /dev/ -name "sd*" ! -name "sda*")
do
        echo $i
done
```

However this includes partitions like `/dev/sdb1`, whereas I only want the root drive like `/dev/sdb`.

How do I modify the find statement to guarantee I don't get any of the numbered files?

Comment: Do you really want to exclude sda or is it a wrong example?

Comment: I do want to exclude sda. When the script is finished, basically all the drives in the machine will have all their data erased. I don't want that to happen to sda, as that's where Linux is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use command substition in that manner, you'll end up with problems when word splitting is applied. Just do

```
find /dev/ -regex '/dev/sd[a-z]+' ! -name 'sda'
```

If your true objective is to show base block devices, just look in `/sys/block`.

Comment: After some testing, I've found that this won't pick up drives like /dev/sdaa or /dev/sdab

Comment: @Phil - Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have a single letter after `sd`, no need to use `find`.
In `bash` you can do

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dev in /dev/sd[!a]; do
    echo "$dev"
done
```

The first line is to have no output when no match exist.

**Edit**

To extend to an undetermined number of letters, the glob could be

```
printf '%s\n' /dev/!(sda|*[0-9])
```

where `!(pattern)` means *everything but pattern*, and excluded patterns are, in the specific case `sda` and `*[0-9]` (everything ending in a number).

Extended globs should to be turned on for this to work (i.e. `shopt -s extglob`).

Comment: No need to use a `for` loop, just do `shopt -s nullglob ; printf '%s\n' /dev/sd[!a]`

Comment: @Chris Down: I suppose he want to elaborate more on `"$dev"`, `echo "$dev"` is just a placeholder.

Comment: Why not just `ls /dev/sd[!a]`?

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar, but supporting more than 26 drives (/dev/sdaa)?

Comment: @Phil: see edit in the answer.

Comment: Do you mean `printf '%s\n' /dev/sd!(a|*[0-9])`?

Comment: @Phil: yes. Of course you can do `for dev in /dev/sd!(a|*[0-9]); do whateveryouwant "$dev"; done`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list of disk devices on linux I suggest:

```
paste -s /sys/dev/block/*/uevent | sed -n '/DEVTYPE=disk/s|.*DEVNAME=\(.*\)\t.*|/dev/\1|p'
```

This will give you also list of potential disks like /dev/loop3 or /dev/ram12.

If you want list of real "partitonable" disks, you can ask fdisk:

```
LANG="C" fdisk -l | sed -n 's|^Disk \(/.*/.*\):.*|\1|p'
```

Then you can filter out the sda:

```
LANG="C" fdisk -l | sed -n 's|^Disk \(/.*/.*\):.*|\1|p' | grep -v sda
```

Comment: I may be a noob, but this looks really complicated and error-prone compared to the alternatives.

Comment: Alternatives will fail on many drives. For example hda hdb and other. Also, some *drives* (not partitions) has numbers in name (loop5, ram3, ...). My solution is fast and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are sure you are dealing with sd*'s and not hd*'s

> find /dev/ -name "sd[b-z]"

should do the trick.